# How to change all datetime objects in a list to standard YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, datetime, mysql-python, python-datetime

When I query MySQL with Python and the query has datetime fields then I get this list as a result.

```
[{'_id': 1, 'name': 'index', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 9, 4, 34), 'title': 'DataExtract'}, {'_id': 2, 'name': 'topmenu', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 52, 17), 'title': 'topmenu'}, {'_id': 3, 'name': 'functions_common', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 52, 50), 'title': 'common functions'}, {'_id': 4, 'name': 'leftmenu', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 53, 56), 'title': 'Left Menu'}, {'_id': 5, 'name': 'todo', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 7, 8, 49, 38), 'title': 'Todo'}, {'_id': 6, 'name': 'cron_publish', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 19, 30, 11), 'title': 'Run Publish reports'}, {'_id': 7, 'name': 'test', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 22, 32, 54), 'title': 'test'}, {'_id': 8, 'name': 'help', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 5, 7, 12, 44), 'title': 'Help'}, {'_id': 9, 'name': 'api', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 5, 21, 22, 13), 'title': 'API'}, {'_id': 10, 'name': 'ben', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 4, 11, 37, 3), 'title': 'List of Reports'}]
```

How do I either get the query to return the date fields in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format? Or how do I convert them in the returned list.  When I try to change them by enumerating over the results python throw as error that the dictionary has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime.datetime()` objects you're getting are the standard representation of these objects - if you were expecting strings instead, you could simple convert them with `datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', value)` but keep in mind that the datetime object is a more flexible way of keeping the data around. I'd recommend only formatting the date in a specific way if you're writing it to the screen or a file format that expects a string.

Example:

```
data = [{'_id': 1, 'name': 'index', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 27, 9, 4, 34), 'title': 'DataExtract'}, {'_id': 2, 'name': 'topmenu', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 52, 17), 'title': 'topmenu'}, {'_id': 3, 'name': 'functions_common', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 52, 50), 'title': 'common functions'}, {'_id': 4, 'name': 'leftmenu', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 19, 53, 56), 'title': 'Left Menu'}, {'_id': 5, 'name': 'todo', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 7, 8, 49, 38), 'title': 'Todo'}, {'_id': 6, 'name': 'cron_publish', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 19, 30, 11), 'title': 'Run Publish reports'}, {'_id': 7, 'name': 'test', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 2, 22, 32, 54), 'title': 'test'}, {'_id': 8, 'name': 'help', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 5, 7, 12, 44), 'title': 'Help'}, {'_id': 9, 'name': 'api', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 5, 21, 22, 13), 'title': 'API'}, {'_id': 10, 'name': 'ben', '_cdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 4, 11, 37, 3), 'title': 'List of Reports'}]

for rec in data:
    rec['date_str'] = datetime.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', rec['_cdate'])
```

That would add `'date_str'` field to every record with the format you require. Of course, you could also modify it to overwrite the original value.

Comment: [datetime.isoformat(' ')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) is a bit more convenient (but requires Python 3.7+ I think).